# How to use window.location.reload

Tags: jquery

i am very new to jquery, so any advise and help will be much appreciated.

> The aim is: when a user refreshes a page the below jquery action
>   should take place but i am unsure how to use window.location.reload in the code -
>   any advise help would be much appreciated

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $ window.location.reload(true);
        $(".message-content" ).removeClass( "hide" )
        $(".unlimited-content" ).addClass( "hide" )
        $(".basic-content" ).addClass( "hide" )
        $("#paypal_express_checkout input:first").val("10165346");
    });
});
</script>
```

> i decided to try the below, it partially works as it displays the
>   jquery action but then it does an automatics refresh which does not
>   display the result of the jquery code to be excuted

```
<script>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        $(".message-content" ).removeClass( "hide" )
        $(".unlimited-content" ).addClass( "hide" )
        $(".basic-content" ).addClass( "hide" )
        $("#paypal_express_checkout input:first").val("10165346");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Except your code is invalid. There's one `});` too much, and a lost `$` before `window`.

Comment: Have you tried $('body').bind('beforeunload',function(){
   //do something
});

Comment: hi @amarjeetkumar i tried as you suggested as above but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only a single page, you don't have to bother using

```
$window.location.reload
```

. Whenever a page is refreshed,

```
$document.ready()
```

is invoked automatically.

If there're two pages and you want to reload the first page whenever the second page is refreshed, simply use

```
$document.ready({
    $firstPageWindowName.location.reload()
});
```

from the second page `<script>` tag.